# How to use verbs when demanding?

Tags: verb, imperative

Sorry if this is a stupid question but what verb ending would you use when demanding something?
Examples: "Get me a apple" or "Sing me a song".

Comment: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imperativ_(Modus)

Comment: Was ist der Bezug zur deutschen Sprache?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about the German language.

Comment: While I find the question to be of rather low quality, I think that one can assume that Jimmy wants to know which form of the verb to use in the German language. The examples are probably in English, because he does not know how to do them in German. And in English the forms are the same as the infinitive, which makes the question understandable. Still, I would advise him to get a beginner's book on German grammar.

Comment: I do think that it is about the German language but it shows no research effort so... vote to close

Comment: I agree, but I never find a good close reason for that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why, [the](http://www.dartmouth.edu/~german/Grammatik/Imperative/Imperativ.html) [imperative](http://www.jabbalab.com/blog/1516/commands-in-german-imperative) of course.